# Where to find the ruby executable documentation?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to find the list of command-line arguments available for the ruby executable in http://ruby-doc.com/ but I could not find anything. After a Google search for "ruby interpreter command line options" I could only find [this page](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/options.html), which applies to Ruby 1.4 only. Where can I find the documentation for the ruby executable in an 'official' source, like ruby-doc.com? Thanks!

Comment: `ruby -h` or `man ruby` do the job. Do you want them online?

Comment: Ruby is not like `C`, or `Java`. Ruby files that you write are directly executed. There is no intermediate `.o` or `.class` that is run.

Comment: @Ursus yes, I was refering to online documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest option is to run `man ruby`. It will show your locally installed interpreter options.

Definitive option is the [ruby repository on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby). Navigate to the version you need in the [releases](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/releases) and locate `man/ruby.1` file in the tree. The file contains definitions for CLI arguments.

Example: Ruby 2.3.0 interpreter CLI arguments [definitions are here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_3_0/man/ruby.1).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the Ruby executable". Every Ruby implementation has their own commandline executable. (Actually, come to think of it, SmallRuby and BlueRuby didn't have a commandline executable *at all*.)

And every Ruby implementation has their own commandline flags. That's why there *cannot* be a document explaining all the options: which implementation's options would that document?

For example, JRuby's `--jdb` flag to run under the Java Debugger simply doesn't make sense for IronRuby, Rubinius, MacRuby, Topaz, Cardinal, MRuby, or YARV. Rubinius's flag to turn on the sampling profiler doesn't make sense for implementations that don't have a sampling profiler. Rubinius's flag to turn on the native code JIT compiler doesn't make sense for implementations that don't have a native code JIT compiler. And so on.

However, there are a couple of options that most implementations agree on:

- `-0`
- `-a`
- `-c`
- `-C`
- `-d`
- `-e`
- `-E`
- `-F`
- `-i`
- `-I`
- `-l`
- `-n`
- `-p`
- `-r`
- `-s`
- `-S`
- `-T`
- `-v`
- `-w`
- `-W`
- `-x`

**BUT!!!**

If you look at MRuby, which is the Ruby implementation written by Yukihiro "matz" Matsumoto, Ruby's creator, which is intended to be a lightweight implementation of the minimum core that can still be called "Ruby", it only supports these options:

- `-b           load and execute RiteBinary (mrb) file`
- `-c           check syntax only`
- `-e 'command' one line of script`
- `-v           print version number, then run in verbose mode`
- `--verbose    run in verbose mode`
- `--version    print the version`
- `--copyright  print the copyright`

Of these, `-b` is clearly implementation specific, and `-c`, `-v`, `--version`, and `--copyright` have no runtime impact, so we can interpret this as meaning that `-e` is the only option that **must** be supported by a conforming Ruby implementation … after all, it is the only option supported by the Ruby implementation written by the only person who can legitimately have a say in what it means to *be* "a Ruby implementation".